# how to pull a textbox value into an anchor tag querystring

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

How do I pull a value from an "asp:TextBox" and pass it in an anchor tag?
txtTaskName is my "asp:TextBox"

```
 <a href='EmailManager.aspx?<%# Eval(txtTaskName.Text) %>' runat="server">Add Email Distribution Lists</a>
```

I know this should be simple and I've done it before, but am in a crunch and don't have my old sourcecode. Thanks All.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your control already filled, you can use

```
<a href='EmailManager.aspx?<%=txtTaskName.Text %>'>Add Email Distribution Lists</a>
```

If you want to do it on change, you should use `PostBack="True"` and an `OnTextChanged` event (server side) for `txtTaskName` control, or use Javascript (client side).

Comment: Thank you - this works. I was missing the `PostBack` and `OnTextChanged` event on the `asp:TextBox`. And I had to remove the `runat="server"`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a `<%= ... =>` displaying expression rather than a data-binding expression?

```
<a href='EmailManager.aspx?<%=txtTaskName.Text %>' runat="server">Add Email Distribution Lists</a>
```

I do not think you would have to specify `runat="server"` either in this particular example.

You can get more information on inline expressions from [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112).

Note that this will only work if `txtTaskName.Text` has a value **before** the inline expression is evaluated, else the value will be `string.Empty`.

Comment: Yes, I have tested this example.

Comment: Yes - It works! Thanks. (And, yes I had to take out the runat="server")